# How to solve dependencies installation problem with yarn?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

In my cra (create-react-app) application I have to add tsconfig.json. But there was an issue. To solve this, by googling I executed `rm -rf yarn.lock` and after that my dependencies are not installing. Every time it throws an error: `An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-ckeditor-components: Not found"`

I don't know what I did wrong and how to overcome it. Please help me

Comment: Did you try remove the node_modules folder as well  and reinstall ?

Comment: That's the problem.. For this package 'react-ckeditor-components' dependencies not installed. After removing this from my package.json, the error is gone

Comment: Yes, when you check the package, there is none, so the json returns 'not found'